# Autopopulating field based on values from different field

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, unique-id

When we ID our utilities (water pipes, storm manholes, etc.) we use ID's derived from a grid system. Our city is divided into grids that have a letter and number attached. "J14", "J15", "J16" and so on. That grid value is also assigned a number when a new feature is created. "J14-1" for example.

I already have a unique ID field that has the existing values. I would like to add to this when a new feature is created based on the location it falls within the grid system. We currently are switching asset management systems and no longer have the built in ID functionality that automatically did this. I have looked in to ModelBuilder and attribute rules for ArcGIS Pro but I have not seen a script that can do this and I don't have much Python experience.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to set up (either in ModelBuilder or arcpy) a tool that counts the number of features in each grid square, and then that count is used in Field Calculator: NewID = GridID + Count. So if J14 has five features in it you get a field with J14-5.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This method would work if we had not deleted certain ID's over time. In grid I15, the next number up is 219. However, since some have been deleted there are currently only 180 features in that grid. Is there a way I could I could do this for the number with the greatest value?

Comment: In a strictly numerical field you can do summary statistics to get the maximum value for a given field. Not sure how this would work on a text fields. Although with python and string splicing you can certainly break a text field into component pieces.